# Where should one ask commercial purchasing questions?

Tags: discussion

I'd like to ask the following question:

```
Where can I purchase the second violin parts of the Tchaikovsky Symphonies numbers 3 & 4?
```

The FAQ clearly states that one should not ask for "shopping or buying recommendations". I'm assuming that rules out my question? Where should I ask it instead?

Comment: You could try our chatroom for this sort of question, but I would guess that (beyond searching the sites linked in the post Luke linked) your best bet is a forum dedicated to finding sheet music.  I don't know of one offhand, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "shopping or buying recommendations" clause of the FAQ is more referring to questions like this one: [Sheet Music Books [closed]](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/6630/1678). My opinion is that this question would be closed on the grounds that it is to localized.

However, this question, "[Sites with a good selection of sheet music](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/696/1678)" may provide sites that have this piece. I'd recommend looking through some of them.

**EDIT:**

I followed my own advice and checked the IMSLP site and found links to the [Symphony No. 3](http://erato.uvt.nl/files/imglnks/usimg/7/7f/IMSLP38500-PMLP02729-Tchaikovsky-Op29.Violin2.pdf) and [Symphony No. 4](http://petrucci.mus.auth.gr/imglnks/usimg/0/07/IMSLP38512-PMLP02735-Tchaikovsky-Op36.Violin2.pdf) Violin II parts. Both are public domain in all countries now unless you're after a recent transcription.

Comment: Thanks Luke - I wasn't after you doing my searching for me, honest, but it's very useful that you did!

Comment: I was a bit curious myself to see if it was there, and when I found it, I decided I might as well show you. IMSLP is a very good site for finding classical sheet music. Take a look around it if you're ever looking for something again.